# How to move a stream in one depot to another depot in Accurev?

Tags: version-control

A stream has already been parented in an existing depot.  However, this stream does not belong there and would better reside in another depot.  How to move an existing stream to another depot?

Comment: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/accurev/en/latest/online/Content/AccuRev-OnLine-Help/sb_reparenting.html

Comment: @Gantendo - This only works with streams in the same depot.

Comment: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/accurev/en/latest/online/Content/AccuRev-OnLine-Help/Change_Palette.html